# Aws - Cloudformation - Fn::Equals Error , Conditions can only be boolean operations on parameters and other conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create ACL's based on the Environment and have the following condition.

```
Global: 
Env: stage 
Region: us-west -1 

Conditions:
  IsStage:  Fn::Equals [!Ref "Env", "stage"]

Resources:

publicIngressVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
    Condition: IsStage
    Properties:
      NetworkAclId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub ${VpcStack}-publicNetworkAclId
      RuleNumber: 150
      Protocol: -1 # tcp
      RuleAction: allow
      CidrBlock: Some VPC
      PortRange:
        From: 1024
        To: 65535
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Template format error: Conditions can only be boolean operations on parameters and other conditions
```

Comment: What is `Env` actually? Please post a more complete example (see [MCVE]).

Comment: Here's what ENV indicates:                                                                                           ```                                                                                                                    
  Global:
  Env: stage
  Region: us-west -1                                                                                                 
 ```

Comment: Please edit your question to include definition of `Env`. Its is still not clear from your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Conditions:
  IsStage:  
    !Equals [ !Ref Env, 'stage' ]
```

Comment: Hi @WarrenG - Sorry for the earlier post , i thought it worked but its back to the same error of                                                                                                                    ```                                                                                                                                      Template format error: Conditions can only be boolean operations on parameters and other conditions ```